# Tessellation Loop in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, hexagonal-grid

I'm new to tessellation within ArcMap however I need it to produce a grid for millions of data points within a shapefile I have.

My logical flow is to generate a tessellation grid, spatially join one-to-many for my points and generate a count field. IF that count field is less than or equal to 50, I'd like to keep that hexbin. HOWEVER, if the count field is GREATER than 50, I'd like to rerun the tessellation grid and repeat until there are 50 points within a single bin.

In this case 50 is an arbitrary number we've just came up with, if it will be easier to have 100 points per bin that's OK too.

We are working with a global dataset however so there's 1 million + points for the individual countries and unfortunately we've been tasked to NOT BREAK UP the points by country.

I've attached my model thus far but I have a feeling this may be simpler to do in python. ModelBuilder is our first choice however due to the level of comprehension the folks this targets.

[image: Current thoughts for workflow]

Comment: While possible to do so in ModelBuilder, we opted for the python option. The model got too confusing for a basic arc user so we scripted a python toolbox instead. Will share code once it's polished.

Comment: If you have the code ready and wish to share then use a flag to ask any moderator to re-open your question, or just ping me using @ in front of my user name.